# Как определить текущий DispatcherPriority из метода который выполняет Dispatcher?

Tags: c#, wpf

Как определить текущий `DispatcherPriority` из метода который выполняет `Dispatcher`? Если я запускаю какой–то метод через `Dispatcher` с приоритетом (для примера) `Input`, то как узнать из самого метода, с каким приоритетом он выполняется?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В принципе можно, хотя я не вполне понимаю, зачем это вам.

Вот такой класс у меня работает:

```
class DispatcherSpy : IDisposable
{
    public DispatcherSpy(Dispatcher dispatcher)
    {
        this.dispatcher = dispatcher;
        dispatcher.Hooks.OperationCompleted += OnOperationCompletion;
        dispatcher.Hooks.OperationStarted += OnOperationStart;
    }

    public DispatcherPriority? CurrentOperationPriority { get; private set; }

    void OnOperationStart(object sender, DispatcherHookEventArgs e) =>
        CurrentOperationPriority = e.Operation.Priority;

    void OnOperationCompletion(object sender, DispatcherHookEventArgs e) =>
        CurrentOperationPriority = null;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        dispatcher.Hooks.OperationStarted -= OnOperationStart;
        dispatcher.Hooks.OperationCompleted -= OnOperationCompletion;
    }

    readonly Dispatcher dispatcher;
}
```

Пользоваться так:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    DispatcherSpy spy;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Loaded += (o, args) =>
            {
                spy = new DispatcherSpy(this.Dispatcher);
                this.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(Callback, DispatcherPriority.Input);
            };
        Unloaded += (o, args) => spy.Dispose();
    }

    void Callback()
    {
        var priority = spy.CurrentOperationPriority;
        Console.WriteLine(priority);
    }
}
```

`DispatcherSpy` должен быть запущен *до* старта метода, который будет запрашивать своё состояние.